# BeautifulSoup returning "None"

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I am writing a script to parse my submissions from a website called codeforces. The current code looks like this (might skip to the get_code() function):

```
import requests
import sys
import queue
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

BASE_URL = "https://codeforces.com/api/user.status"

def get_input():
  if len(sys.argv) < 3:
    print("handle and/or path to save file not provided!")
    print("info: ./app.py <handle> <path-to-directory>")
    sys.exit()
  global PARAMS
  PARAMS = {
    "handle": sys.argv[1],
    "from": 1,
    "count": 10000
  }
  global BASE_PATH
  BASE_PATH = sys.argv[2]
  if BASE_PATH[-1:] != '/':
    BASE_PATH += '/'

def download_data():
  res = requests.get(url = BASE_URL, params = PARAMS)
  global data
  data = res.json()

def prepare_queue():
  global q
  q = queue.LifoQueue(maxsize = PARAMS["count"])
  for sub in data["result"]:
    if sub["verdict"] == "OK":
      q.put({
        "id": sub["id"],
        "contest": sub["contestId"],
        "index": sub["problem"]["index"],
        "lang": sub["programmingLanguage"]
      })

def download_submissions():
  while not q.empty():
    i = q.get()
    download_code(i)
    print("downloaded:", i)

def download_code(sub):
  URL = "https://codeforces.com/contest/{}/submission/{}".format(sub["contest"], sub["id"])
  code = requests.get(url = URL)
  code = get_code(code.content)
  save_code(code, sub)
  
def get_code(html):
  soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html5lib")
  code = str(soup.find("pre", attrs = {"id":"program-source-text", "style":"padding: 0.5em;"}))
  print (code)
  return code

def save_code(code, meta):
  path = BASE_PATH + str(meta["contest"]) + meta["index"]
  path = path + get_extension(meta["lang"])
  f = open(path, "w")
  f.write(code)
  print("written file:", path)
  f.close()

def get_extension(lang):
  lang = lang.lower()
  if "java" in lang:
    return ".java"
  elif "c++" in lang:
    return ".cpp"
  elif "go" in lang:
    return ".go"
  elif "kotlin" in lang:
    return ".kt"
  elif "python" in lang:
    return ".py"
  elif "rust" in lang:
    return ".rs"
  elif "c#" in lang:
    return ".cs"
  else:
    return ""

get_input()
download_data()
prepare_queue()
download_submissions()
```

The only thing that probably matters is the function get_code()

```
def get_code(html):
  soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html5lib")
  code = str(soup.find("pre", attrs = {"id":"program-source-text", "style":"padding: 0.5em;"}))
  print (code)
  return code
```

The problem is, it returns "None" instead of returning my code. For reference, use [This](https://codeforces.com/contest/313/submission/86832830) submission.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The site uses `RCPC` cookie that is computed at the beginning. It seems it doesn't change, so you can use this script to download the code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = 'https://codeforces.com/contest/313/submission/86832830'

cookies = {'RCPC':'9f40a755922f793026d1b457e3fb688c'}
url = re.search(r'document\.location\.href="(.*?)"', requests.get(url).text).group(1)

soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url, cookies=cookies).content, 'html.parser')
code = str(soup.find("pre", attrs = {"id":"program-source-text", "style":"padding: 0.5em;"}))
print(code)
```

Prints:

```
<pre class="prettyprint lang-cpp linenums program-source" id="program-source-text" style="padding: 0.5em;">#include &lt;bits/stdc++.h&gt;
using namespace std;
#define fo(int, i, a, b)        for (int i=a; i&lt;(b); i++)
#define forev(int, i, b, a)     for (int i = (b)-1; i &gt;= a; i--)
#define uns                     unsigned
#define lli                     long long int
#define ld                      long double
#define all(x)                  x.begin(), x.end()
#define sortall(x)              sort(all(x))
#define enl                     "\n"
// #define PI 3.1415926535897932384626
// const int MOD = 1000000007; const lli INF = 1e18; const int MX = 100001;

void solve() {
    int n, m;
    string s; cin &gt;&gt; s &gt;&gt; m;
    n = s.length();
    int arr[n], sum[n] = {0};
    fo(int, i , 1, n) {
        if (s[i] == s[i - 1]) arr[i] = 1; else arr[i] = 0;
        sum[i] = sum[i - 1] + arr[i];
    }
    int l, r, ans = 0;
    fo(int, i, 0, m) {
        cin &gt;&gt; l &gt;&gt; r;
        ans = 0;
        ans += sum[r - 1] - sum[l - 1];
        cout &lt;&lt; ans &lt;&lt; enl;
        // cout &lt;&lt; sum[l - 1] &lt;&lt; " " &lt;&lt; sum[r - 1] &lt;&lt; enl;
    }
}

int main() {
    ios_base::sync_with_stdio(0); cin.tie(0);
    // int testcase; cin &gt;&gt; testcase; for (int i = 1; i &lt;= testcase; ++i)
    solve();
    return 0;
}</pre>
```

Comment: Thank you, turned out that the website had just implemented RCPC a day before this question, making me wonder why suddenly all my scripts (and other people's scripts stopped working. Again, thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

To get the text you could use `.find(text=True)`:

```
code = soup.find("pre", attrs = {"id":"program-source-text", "style":"padding: 0.5em;"}).find(text=True)
```

Or just pull the first element from `.contents`:

```
code = soup.find("pre", attrs = {"id":"program-source-text", "style":"padding: 0.5em;"}).contents[0]
```